# Access text file content from USB storage automatically from a server

Tags: authentication, applet, native, file-permissions

I want to read the content of a text file (serves as a key) stored inside a USB mass storage **automatically** when the user is authenticated by his matching username and password for that website. It's like the textfile(key) is the **extended authentication**.

I think this needs to can be done by a (1) **native program**? or an (2) **applet**? What do i need to study? Can someone give me an overview for the process to make this possible?

Quite good in web tech but not with native app.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more details about what extra details you are looking for. Is it to do with web page <> app communication, or more details about how to use the file system API, or because you're hoping there might be another way to do this?

Comment: What kind of system/OS are you wanting to do this on?

Comment: windows at home, mac at work

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access USB mass storage devices through chrome.usb as they are claimed and handled by the host operating system.

Instead you could use the chrome.fileSystem API, but the user will need to select the file. Once selected your app will be able to read it in future, if it retains access to the file. See the [API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) for more details.

Comment: this must be done automatically. Like when the user successfully login using his/here username and password, the server that is using my plugin/api, will find the specific txtfile stored inside a usb drive

Answer (score 1):

If you want this only for Internet Explorer, You can create an Active X. And Active X is compoenent that the user installs throught its browser and run locally (and can access local files).

Answer (score 0):

Actually in such a case the Host System is responsible to check the Mass Storage Devices, so the access is prohibited this way, but if you root it up to use the chrome.fileSystem.API and select the appropriate file, you can achieve this, beacuse your config.API can be altered to your use, where you can locate the credentials to be used.(If you know the exact Path)

In windows based systems a false trojan can also do the purpose by making a replication of the filesystem. Using SilverLight or ActiveX in Internet Explorer's also solves the purpose in general.

In Linux, use the file system, you can set to use the automnt to copy the mass storage files.

Comment: still if you can share some more details to the question, may be the answer could be more generic

Comment: it must be automatically, it will be undesirable if a user will always look for the keyfile

Comment: you need not search for the keyfile manually you can configure the api to search for the file

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html check this API documentation out

Comment: how is this when implemented, i mean how does chrome API allowed this communication considering security issues

Comment: to solve this issue chrome has got an internal GUID check for the process through which the respective application is being synced in case of failure it gets restored to last good known state. For this you need to manually configure some API's to search for the respective file located in the file system to get the pass key details

Comment: for this you need to learn how to configure chrome API's just as an Example [API Examples](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try building a .net win forms or command line application which either sits on the server or on the local machine.

This site might help with the usb access: [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)

Might also be worth considering a web service to post the key to the server.

Answer (score -1):

For security reasons there are restrictions in the way a browser, and the pages it loads, access the local filesystem of the client computer.

Is it safe to assume you only require this to work on a specific browser? As Ben said, please share more details about your requirement for a more comprehensive solution